# Main promise chain not waiting for Parse.Query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm attempting to run a Parse.Query in my `matchCenterComparison` function, which is part of the main promise chain below.

When I run this code, it logs out `('setup query criteria, about to run it');` and `('MatchCenterComparison Succeeded bro!')`, but not the `console.log` within `userCategoryThingQuery.find().then`.

I've researched this online, and looked through the [Parse.Query Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html), and my conclusion is that the main promise chain isn't waiting for `userCategoryThingQuery` to finish, since it's asynchronous. Is this what's causing the problem? If so, how can I fix this?

**Main Promise Chain:**

```
Parse.Cloud.job("MatchCenterBackground", function(request, status) {
    // ... other code to setup usersQuery ...
  var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

  usersQuery.each(function (user) {
    return processUser(user).then(function(eBayResults){
      return matchCenterComparison(eBayResults);
    });
  }).then(function() {
    status.success("background job worked brah!");
  }, function(error) {
    status.error(error);
  });
});
```

**matchCenterComparison Function:**

```
function matchCenterComparison(eBayResults) {   

        console.log('eBayResults are the following:' + eBayResults);

        var matchCenterComparisonPromise = new Parse.Promise();

        if (eBayResults.length > 0) {
          // do some work, possibly async
          console.log('yes the ebay results be longer than 0');


          var userCategoryThing = Parse.Object.extend("userCategory");
          var userCategoryThingQuery = new Parse.Query(userCategoryThing);
          userCategoryThingQuery.contains('categoryId', '9355');

          console.log('setup query criteria, about to run it');

          userCategoryThingQuery.find().then(function(results) {
            console.log('lets see what we got here:' + results);
          });


        matchCenterComparisonPromise.resolve(console.log('MatchCenterComparison Succeeded bro!'));
      } else {
        matchCenterComparisonPromise.reject({ message: 'No work done, expression failed' });
      }
      return matchCenterComparisonPromise;  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
function(request, status) {
    // ... other code to setup usersQuery ...
  var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

  usersQuery.each(function (user) {
    return processUser(user).then(function(eBayResults){
      return matchCenterComparison(eBayResults);
    });
  })
```

Here's a question - what does this function return?

Answer - it returns undefined. It doesn't return a promise, and therefore the chain has nothing to wait on.

What you need to do is take all the promises from your loop over usersQuery and return a promise that doesn't complete until they all do. Try rewriting like this:

```
function(request, status) {
    // ... other code to setup usersQuery ...
  var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

  return usersQuery.each(function (user) {
    return processUser(user).then(function(eBayResults){
      return matchCenterComparison(eBayResults);
    });
  }))
```

Looking at the docs for Parse.Query, the important bits are this:

> If the callback returns a promise, the iteration will not continue
>   until that promise has been fulfilled.

and

> Returns: {Parse.Promise} A promise that will be fulfilled once the
>   iteration has completed.

So this should get you what you want - the usersQuery.each call will return a promise that completes when the iteration ends, and returning the promise from inside the callback will mean the iteration doesn't complete until after all the items have been processed.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Is there any reason why you're using `usersQuery.map` instead of `usersQuery.each`? I'm getting an error stating `Failed with: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'map'` when I try that.

Comment: And using `usersQuery.each` gives me this bizzare error: `Failed with: TypeError: Object function (){this._resolved=!1,this._rejected=!1,this._resolvedCallbacks=[],this._rejectedCallbacks=[]} has no method 'all'
    at main.js:756:24
 ` referencing that exact line.

Comment: Ah, ok - I misunderstood the code. I was assuming usersQuery was just an array. What does usersQuery.each actually return then? I assume it's not a promise if you're getting that error. I'm not familiar with the parse api. The important thing is you need to end up with a promise that completes after all the items have been processed.

Comment: usersQuery queries through every `user` object in the database, and runs `processUser` and `matchCenterComparison` for every `user` object returned by that query. According to the [docs here](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html), it seems like this is an asynch operation. Does this qualify as a promise? Sorry if I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Thanks for the doc pointer - I've updated my answer based on this information.